# How can I put this option underneath?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this select input example

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqp98rua/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="select-style3">
        <select name="mailing_state" id="state" class=" select-full required-input copy-data">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>


    </select>   
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.select-style3 {
    background-image: url("/public/images/arrow-field.png"), linear-gradient(to right, white 70%, white 70%, gray 71%, lightgray 71%, lightgray 100%);
    background-position: 80px center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 113px;
    height: 30px;
}
.select-style3 select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select-style3 select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

If you select from the list `District of Columbia` then you will see that bad element seen ...

I wish to pass underneath and just look so bad ...

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the text is too wide. What do you _want_ it to do?  Why not just make it wider?

Comment: width: 190px; instead of 113px;

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the `width` of the element: `width: 113px;` is too narrow for the text.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.select-style3 {
    background-image: url("/public/images/arrow-field.png"), linear-gradient(to right, white 70%, white 70%, gray 71%, lightgray 71%, lightgray 100%);
    background-position: 80px center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 190px;
    height: 30px;

}
.select-style3 select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select-style3 select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bqp98rua/1/)